# How to create a transition matrix in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to calculate the number of following events in a month say January, 1950 to form transition probability matrix of Markov chain:

```
E00 = dry day after dry day
E01 = wet day after dry day
E10 = dry day after wet day
E11 = wet day after wet day
```

Dry day means rainfall = 0 and wet day means rainfall>0.

How can I calculate these above using R? I have tried my best to write a function with logical statements but cannot. Could anyone please help me?

data:

```
day,month,year,rainfall
1,01,1950,0.586212158
2,01,1950,1.202758789
3,01,1950,0
4,01,1950,0
5,01,1950,0
6,01,1950,0.183441162
7,01,1950,4.675704956
8,01,1950,9.258003235
9,01,1950,3.425468445
10,01,1950,0
11,01,1950,0
12,01,1950,8.39233E-05
13,01,1950,0
14,01,1950,0
15,01,1950,0.641731262
16,01,1950,9.325141907
17,01,1950,5.588417053
18,01,1950,0.903343201
19,01,1950,3.892127991
20,01,1950,0.133895874
21,01,1950,0.102630615
22,01,1950,5.334564209
23,01,1950,1.017593384
24,01,1950,0
25,01,1950,0.621734619
26,01,1950,0.957794189
27,01,1950,3.131622314
28,01,1950,4.868865967
29,01,1950,0.169281006
30,01,1950,0
31,01,1950,0
```

Comment: Do you mean "How do I estimate a transition matrix from data like these?"

Comment: Comments about programming are better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, Glen_b and user2005253. I have got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do what I assume you're after (it's possible to be briefer):

```
# assuming the data is read into a data frame called "raindata"
rf <- raindata$rainfall
n <- length(rf)
rainedf <- as.factor(ifelse(rf,0,1))
trf <- table(data.frame(yesterday=rainedf[1:(n-1)],today=rainedf[2:n]))
trf/rowSums(trf)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do this also for a higher markov chain? How would it look like then?

Comment: If you mean "higher order" then 1. Yes, it's possible 2. the matrix will be a lot bigger, because you make pairs of rainy-day events as source states, akin to the second matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Music) and so the line with `table` must work with those `previous.two.days` states in place of `yesterday` (you'd also want a lot more data to support that estimation).