# Creating a transition matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like a transition probability matrix that looks like this (adding up to 1.0 for each row).

```
0.00   0.00   1.00   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.00   0.50   0.50   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.33   0.00   0.33   0.33  0.00   0.00   0.00
```

How can I get it in R?

Comment: and would like a transition probability matrix that looks like this (adding up to 1.0 for each row).

0.00   0.00   1.00   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.00   0.50   0.50   0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00
0.33   0.00   0.33   0.33  0.00   0.00   0.00

Comment: It may be duplicate. See the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824596/how-to-create-a-transition-matrix-in-r | Or the markovchain package may be useful - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
transMatrx <-matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,.5,.5,0,0,0,0,.33,0,.33,.33,0,0,0),nrow=6)
```

nrow=6 is the amount of columns

Go left to right, top to bottom